# EXCEPTION: Unsupported operation: RawSocket constructor (Dart with sqljocky5: ^2.2.1)

Tags: mysql, dart, database-connection, sqljocky

I am trying to connect dart with a MySQL database.  I installed the MySQL workbench and created a simple DB, have modified the pubspec.yaml and added any other dependencies I needed for MySQL. But I keep pulling up an exception in the browser.

> EXCEPTION: Unsupported operation: RawSocket constructor
>   STACKTRACE: dart:sdk_internal connect package:sqljocky5/comm/buffered_socket.dart 60:7 defaultSocketFactory package:sqljocky5/comm/buffered_socket.dart 72:20 connect dart:sdk_internal async package:sqljocky5/comm/buffered_socket.dart 70:6 connect package:sqljocky5/comm/comm.dart 163:26 connect dart:sdk_internal async package:sqljocky5/comm/comm.dart 156:53 connect package:sqljocky5/connection/impl.dart 102:22 connect dart:sdk_internal async package:sqljocky5/connection/impl.dart 101:64 connect package:sqljocky5/connection/connection.dart 36:7 connect package:pbcat_form/src/start/start.dart 84:22 main dart:sdk_internal async package:pbcat_form/src/start/start.dart 75:10 main package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 134:16  dart:sdk_internal run package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 131:12 [_run] dart:sdk_internal runGuarded package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 302:22 runGuarded package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 582:7  package:sqljocky5/comm/buffered_socket.dart 70:6 connect package:sqljocky5/comm/comm.dart 163:26 connect dart:sdk_internal async package:sqljocky5/comm/comm.dart 156:53 connect package:sqljocky5/connection/impl.dart 102:22 connect dart:sdk_internal async package:sqljocky5/connection/impl.dart 101:64 connect package:sqljocky5/connection/connection.dart 36:7 connect package:pbcat_form/src/start/start.dart 84:22 main dart:sdk_internal async package:pbcat_form/src/start/start.dart 75:10 main package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 134:16  dart:sdk_internal run package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 131:12 [_run] dart:sdk_internal runGuarded package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 302:22 runGuarded package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 582:7

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be doing this :-

RawSocket.connect(host, port);

However there is no connect method on RawSocket, see [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/RawSocket-class.html)

This may have changed in Dart 2.2, the get/set RawOption methods have been added for instance

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/RawSocket/connect.html

Answer (score 0):

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/RawSocket/connect.html

external static Future connect(host, int port,
    {sourceAddress, Duration timeout});

Comment: please use "`" to format your code and add details to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try running the app on an android emulator, rather than a web emulator